# Firefox VERY unresponsive when browsing to repl.it

Tags: firefox, performance, browser, unresponsive

I'm using Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit) and it's always pretty fast, but whenever I go to `repl.it` my browser becomes very unresponsive and everything. I tried using MS Edge and it worked just fine, the animation on the homepage plays and I can click on everything and I can close tabs and open them.

**EDIT**: This only happens to me on the *homepage* of `repl.it`, all other pages work just fine.

**UPDATE**: I checked Task-Manager and my GPU-usage was over 98%. My GPU is AMD Radeon R7 Graphics, if that's usable info.

Can anyone please explain me (or provide a fix) why Firefox is sooooo slow and unresponsive?

Comment: *Can anyone please explain me (or provide a fix) why Firefox is sooooo slow and unresponsive?* No, we can't, because it isn't. I just tested and it opens the homepage quite fast.

Comment: It might have been your geolocation at the time. Or your ISP. Or your browser, or your computer, or your router.... There are hundreds of reasons why one website might load slow.

Comment: @dsstorefile: How can I check if multiprocess is enabled? BTW: Just updated my question